# Turn off Internet Access; Leave Intranet On

Tags: windows-xp, sonicwall, internet

I have a machine running Windows XP SP3 on a domain run by a server running Windows Server 2003 for our DNS. We also have a sonic wall firewall. We use the XP machine to receive faxes and scan documents into a queue. Queue is read by Linux server for web-based software application.

The goal is to either

1. shut off internet/www access and leave all local capabilities in tact
2. find another way of receiving faxes without having to reroute phone lines in the office.

Upgrading to Win7, or replacing the box won't solve my problem since I don't know enough about the Linux server and/or the web-based software it runs to just change where the server reads the faxes from.

Anything helps. Thanks.

Comment: There is a stunning lack of enough information here for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Windows Firewall.

Comment: @NathanC could you make that an actual answer? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Nathan...Found what I need under exceptions tab. My apologies to the community for being a dunce.

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows Firewall to accomplish this. Block *all* traffic except for what you need for the scanning functions. If you're just looking to block web access, block incoming/outgoing 80/443 traffic. This has a side effect of making Windows Updates not work, but since XP is out of support anyway that doesn't matter anymore.